# Не работают медиазапросы на мобильных устройствах и в эмуляторе Chrome

Tags: css, responsive

Если изменяю ширину окна браузера, то запросы срабатывают, а как только включаю эмуляцию разных устройств в хроме - не работает, на телефон скидывал вёрстку - тоже не работает. Там сетка из картинок 4 на 3, при 900 и меньше должны по два в ряду быть, при 500 и меньше - по одному. Но они уменьшаются пропорционально размеру окна, оставаясь по 4 в ряд, это за счёт единиц vw, но тогда почему в браузере на компьютере работает всё, и становятся по 2, а потом по 1.

```
 .wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.row div {
    width: 19.033674963396777vw;
    height: 19.033674963396777vw;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #a9a9a9;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;

@media (max-width: 900px) {
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
}
.row {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
}
.row div {
    width: 32.77vw;
    height: 32.77vw
    }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
.row div {
    width: 70vw;
    height: 70vw
    }
}
```

Comment: эта строчка в head есть? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: гм, гм) ну почему я постоянно сыплюсь на таких мелочах..